# (xcode) (opencv) error cannot convert 'obj_object*' to 'iplimage*' in initialization

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv

Excuse me, I got the following error while calling function :
[self createIplImageFromUIImage:img1];

here is the code:

```
 IplImage *imgTemplate = [self CreateIplImageFromUIImage:img1];
```

and this is the error detail

```
error: cannot convert 'objc_object*' to 'IplImage*' in initialization
```

currently I'm using xcode 4.4.1 and ios 5.1 also opencv from aptogo website.. maybe 2.4.2

*EDIT (SOLVED)

```
 IplImage *imgTemplate =(IplImage *)[self CreateIplImageFromUIImage:img1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help:

```
IplImage *imgTemplate = [[IplImage alloc] init];
imgTemplate = [self CreateIplImageFromUIImage:img1];
```

Comment: no you cannot do that... IplImage is not objective-c class... it's from OpenCV....